# Why do rectangular matrices have no inverse that can solve Ax = v?

Tags: linear-algebra

We can reverse a linear transformation using an inverse matrix to find the input vector used in the original linear transformation:

$$A^{-1}A\vec{x} = A^{-1}\vec{v}$$

Let's say we have a 2D vector that we transform into a 1D "vector":
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b 
\end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} 
x  \\ 
y   
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
ax + by
\end{pmatrix}       $$

**Isn't there some matrix that can then convert that 1D vector back into the original 2D vector?** Something like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
c  \\ 
d 
\end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix} 
ax + by
\end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 
x  \\ 
y  
\end{pmatrix}      $$

My TA says that the original transformation does not have an inverse because **a single input vector would map to multiple  output vectors**. But I'm not seeing those multiple outputs in my algebra.

Comment: In the direction from $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ to $(ax+by)$ you have multiple **inputs** that map to a single **output**. But now you want to reverse the direction of the transformation, so what was your output is now your input and what used to be your inputs are ... (I'll let you finish that sentence). Can you see the "multiple outputs" now?

Answer (score 5):

The point is that there are infinitely many vectors $\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}$ that would give the same $ax+by$.  For example, if $a=1$ and $b=1$, $\pmatrix{1 & 1} \pmatrix{t\cr -t\cr} = 0$ for all $t$.  So how is your inverse going to take that $0$ and find out what $t$ it came from?

Answer (score 2):

*Some* rectangular matrices have left inverses which can be used to solve the equation $Ax=v$ where $v$ is in the span of the columns of $A$. Specifically, if $A$ is a rectangular matrix of full rank having more rows than columns, then the "left inverse" of $A$ equals $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ so that $$Ax=v \implies x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tv$$ This is only true if $v$ belongs to the column space of $A$. On the other hand, if $v\notin \text{Col}(A)$, then $x^*=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tv$ happens to be the least squares solution to the inconsistent system $Ax=v$ i.e. it's "the best you can do," and $Ax^*$ is the projection of $b$ onto the span of the columns of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

When it exists, the solution of a linear system
$$\eqalign{
AX &= B \\
}$$
can be written using the Moore-Penrose inverse $A^+$ and an arbitrary matrix $Y$ as
$$\eqalign{
X &= A^+B + (I_n-A^+A)Y \\
}$$
When the dimensions of the matrices $(A,B,X,Y)$ are
$\Big((1\times 2),\,(1\times 1),\,(2\times 1),\,(2\times1)\Big)$ you'd rewrite this in terms of vectors and scalars $(a,\beta,x,y)$ as
$$\eqalign{a^Tx = \beta}$$
Since the pseudoinverse of a vector has a closed-form $\Big(a^+ = \frac{a^T}{a^Ta}\Big)$ so does the solution
$$\eqalign{
x = \beta\left(\frac{a}{a^Ta}\right) + \left(I_2-\left(\frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}\right)\right)y \\
}$$
Which is great -- except that there are an *infinite* number of possible
$y$ vectors, and so there are an infinite number of solutions.